# SQL Error, Column Doesn't Exist

Tags: sql, join

The following error:

```
Unknown column 'Customers.Customer_ID' in 'on clause'
```

Is a result of this code:

```
SELECT First_Name, Last_Name, Orders.Order_ID, Orders.Order_Date, Orders.Plant_ID, Orders.Plant_Qty, Orders.Price, Orders.Employee_ID
FROM Customers, Orders
INNER JOIN Orders as t2
ON Customers.Customer_ID = t2.Order_ID;
```

I cannot work out why; Customers.Customer_ID is a field in the Customers table?

Comment: Look at this. `FROM Customers, Orders
INNER JOIN Orders as t2` What is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably because it's ambiguous. You need to remove `FROM .. Orders` since it looks like you're trying to do an explicit join. I would also recommend prefixing all column names in your column list. You should also stick to an alias or the table name on your join.

```
SELECT customers.first_name, 
       customers.last_name, 
       orders.order_id, 
       orders.order_date, 
       orders.plant_id, 
       orders.plant_qty, 
       orders.price, 
       orders.employee_id 
FROM   customers 
       INNER JOIN orders  
               ON customers.customer_id = orders.order_id;
```

Comment: It's out of scope rather than ambiguous if ansi 89 and 92 joins are mixed the 89 ones are treated as joining last so customers isn't available in the on clause.

Comment: This also tells me Orders.Order_ID is an unknown collumn

Comment: @DannyHickerz Could you please post your table schemas?

Comment: @DannyHickerz What DBMS are you using? (MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle)

Comment: The questions been answered but im still curious how to use it. phpMyAdmin.

Comment: @DannyHickerz You would run the query `SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl_name`

Answer (score 0):

I believe that `Customers -> Orders` *(one to many relationship)* and you're trying to join the table *one to one relationship*, correct me if i am wrong. so the query should like this.

```
SELECT First_Name, Last_Name, Orders.Order_ID, Orders.Order_Date, Orders.Plant_ID, Orders.Plant_Qty, Orders.Price, Orders.Employee_ID
FROM Customers
INNER JOIN Orders as t2
ON Customers.Customer_ID = t2.Customer_ID;
```

Comment: Yes, you're right about the one to many relationship. Im trying to show every field in the order table and list the customer firstname and last name using the query.

Comment: okay, the query should like `Customers.Customer_ID = Orders.Customer_ID;` `Customer_ID` -> where the foreign key of Customer table to `Orders table`